# Crystal Reports - Selecting pieces of data from a string

Tags: string, extract

I am simply trying to pull data from a a string.
{dp.div-amt} comes out as 0;0;3.50;0;0;4.75;0;0;6.50

Each one is a month as dividends are paid quarterly.  It loops over itself each month.
I am needing the most current dividends paid, which would be the third month (3.50).
I can see the data, but I need it for a report and can't figure out how to get to it.

This was suggested:

```
Local stringVar i;
Local Stringvar inString = {Table.FieldName};
Local stringVar array arr := Split(inString, ";");

for i := 1 to Count (arr) do
(arr[i] := Mid(arr[i],4,5) + ":" + Mid(arr[i],6,7);)
```

I have tried it and variations without any luck. Help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression:

```
Split({dp.div-amt}, ";")[3];
```